# spring session collision sessions

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-session

In spring session we have two applications that use the same redis server and as a results sometimes we get ClassNotFoundException unable to serialize, due to the fact that an app tries to serialize a session created by a different app. Sometimes both services starts to give this error though.

In order to mitigate this issue we have identified to use `redisNamespace`. However lets say if we have 2 services and only is able to update one service. If we add `redisNamespace` to one service would there be no collisions of sessions on either service? e.g. Service A has namespace of "test" while Service B has the default "" namespace (would service B still try and use Service A's sessions?), or do we need to change the namespace of Service B as well?

Also we haven't been able to consistency reproduce this issue, sometimes the ClassNotFoundException does not come and sometimes is does, any guidelines to consistently recreate this would be very much appreciated.

The spring version we are using is 1.3.1.RELEASE as well.

Comment: Just a small doubt, shouldn't session created by service A, also accessible to service B, otherwise, the user will get logged out, if the request goes from server A to server B?

Comment: Wel actually not necessarily, think of this where we want two separate applications that use the same redis server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redisNamespace` configuration parameter is meant to provide application specific namespace for sessions, in order to support the use case with multiple applications using the same Redis instance to store sessions. From the [`1.3.x` reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.x/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-config):

> `redisNamespace` - allows configuring an application specific namespace for the sessions. Redis keys and channel ids will start with the prefix of `spring:session:<redisNamespace>:`.

So the answer to your question is yes - if one application doesn't configure specific namespace, but the other one that uses the same Redis instance does, they will use different namespaces so no collisions should occur.

As a side note, the semantics of `redisNamespace` have changed in Spring Session 2.0 so that you can now use this parameter to configure the full namespace, rather than only the last part of prefix as in Spring Session 1.3. From the [`2.0.x` reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.x/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-config):

> `redisNamespace` - allows configuring an application specific namespace for the sessions. Redis keys and channel IDs will start with the prefix of `<redisNamespace>:`.